# Android - USB mass storage - create autorun file like autorun.inf in windows

Tags: android, shell, usb, autorun, usb-mass-storage

Is it possible to create autorun file for Android USB mass storage device (disk on key) , put it (autorun file) on the device and when I will plug it to android device it will run.
I wan't to create autorun file that will open a file from the disk on key.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Have u found any solution yet?

Comment: @TobiasTheel No :-( I didn't find any working solution...